# Why are there 2 kinds of controller tests in MiniTest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, minitest, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm converting over to MiniTest from RSpec, and having a couple of difficulties doing so. I have been following some examples I have found:

```
class ArticlesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:articles)
  end
end
```

So that's a class that inherits from *ActionController::TestCase*, that makes sense.

But then there are other examples like this:

```
require 'test_helper'

describe ThingsController do
  describe "#create" do

    it do "valid"
      login_user
      post :create, { catalog: { name: "My Thing", description: "Description of my thing."}}
      assert_redirected_to thing_path(Thing.last)
    end

  end
end
```

Why are these two styles different? I'm using the second example, and none of my redirects are working like they do in my dev system. Trying to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: The first is classic Test::Unit style, the second more Rspec flavour. They should be functionally identical other than in how tests are declared, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one is Minitest::Unit test syntax explained [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)

Second is more like Rspec syntax, you can use [minitest-spec-rails](https://github.com/metaskills/minitest-spec-rails) gem for that